# Why CodeIgniter says having a directory with 777 permission to use file uploading class?

Tags: codeigniter, class, file-upload, permissions, directory

I've heard web developers should not have any directory with 777 permission on their websites because it creates security problems. But why does CodeIgniter ask it in its [File Uploading Class documents](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html)?

Comment: @Sedz, I know 775 works too. But if CodeIgniter team meant any special reason for 777? This is my question.
They absolutely know the risk of 777 ...

Comment: Yes maybe it's a mistake OR they meant to avoid problems with novice developers